# Can I use a windows drive as '/home' for the ubuntu install?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have a windows 7 laptop with 2 drives on HDD both in NTFS, C drive, where windows is installed, and D drive where I store all my files (everything except windows system files and softwares). I want to have a dual boot laptop where I build/port AOSP (Android Open Source Project) on my ubuntu OS and use windows 7 as my other OS. So since I have a lot of space on my D drive I was wondering if I made D drive my '/home' would it be a bad idea? And can I do that and still see all the data on my D drive? I haven't installed my Ubuntu yet, but that's no big deal! ;P. I'm thinking of dedication 8 GB for my swap and 10 GB for root and the rest can be shared in '/home' and drive D, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/home MUST be mounted on a filesystem that supports permissions so that rules out anything microsoft has (ntfs, fat). The directories in /home/$USER/ you can put on an external disc or another partition and can be NTFS.

I would opt for a seperate partition that you format as NTFS and store your documents there. Leave /home empty of private files and you can keep that at 25 Gb.

Comment: My main aim is to build android on the ubuntu. According to [www.source.android.com] "The source download is approximately 8.5GB in size. You will need over 30GB free to complete a single build, and up to 100GB (or more) for a full set of builds." so I don't know if  should assign '100+GB to my '/home' '

Comment: why would you need 100Gb in /home? you can build in any directory if you set it up to do so

Comment: So all that means is there has to be 100GB free in the directory I'm building. That's good, I was very stupid to not think that. Cheers for help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot do this on an install.  You'll probably have to establish the mount manually.

However, I'd be a little concerned as the line terminators between linux and windows are different.  Mixing these files all around in the same home directory could be confusing and cause you to have interoperability problems and a lot of frustration.

Comment: Alright, I might partition Drive D and then use it as '/home'.